# DeWalt 7491RS arbor nut loosens

Tags: blade

I have been using a [DeWalt 7491RS Jobsite Table Saw](https://www.dewalt.com/products/power-tools/saws/table-saws/10-jobsite-table-saw--32--12-825cm-rip-capacity-and-a-rolling-stand/dwe7491rs) since Dec '20 and as it was shutting down after cutting yesterday the blade wouldn't stop on its own. After I stopped it I saw why - the arbor nut was almost off.

I have seen 2 other threads about this issue and noticed that several people said they were going to contact manufacturer and I was wondering, was anyone satisfied with their solution? I called DeWalt and talked to a factory service center person and was treated like I'm quite stupid and had to really fight to get them to agree to see it. Now, of course, I'm concerned that they won't find anything because it took 8 months for the problem to show up. I also don't want to use the saw again because my understanding is that this shouldn't happen at all and it's a serious safety problem. I don't want the blade flying out of the table.

I have a few times let the saw run while turning away to grab another piece of wood. Would the blade loosen if running and not actually cutting?

Any feedback greatly appreciated!

Comment: TBH, based on the number of complaints just on this site, I'd consider trying to get it replaced under the 3 year warranty. There may have been an issue with the saw (the other users complaints were roughly the same time frame as when you got yours). Often times, companies will fix a manufacturing defect, but won't necessarily contact purchasers to have theirs upgraded. DeWalt seems to produce a quality product (have had some of their tools for more than 20yrs, very minimal issues) and I'd imagine that they're willing to stand behind them. _but maybe not in front of this saw... :)_

Comment: As I mention in the other Q&A, it is probably when the saw is powered down that the blades rotate the nut off the arbour. When coming up to speed the blade mass tends to tighten the nut. But, yeah. This is pretty much answered already.

Comment: Thanks, FreeMan, for your answer and for reading the whole post before commenting! I talked to someone else in CS and then called the service center back and was able to get them to agree to give me a new saw.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with my 7491RS. Dewalt has been appallingly unhelpful. They have sent me 3 replacement arbor nuts so far, two of which did not fit my saw (even though I told them the part they were sending wouldn't fit) and the third was not an arbor nut at all. I'm shocked that Dewalt isn't addressing an obvious safety issue. I ended up buying my own replacement arbor nut since Dewalt said they were back ordered. If that doesn't fix I'll push for a new saw. Mine is only a year old and I haven't used it that much